# SilverStripe convertDataObjectSet is stripping additional properties

Tags: silverstripe

I am attempting to add the 'AbsoluteLink' property to each DataObject in a DataList and then convert the list to JSON with `JSONDataFormatter::convertDataObjectSet()`.

**I have the following function:**

```
public function json() {
    $data      = ResourceCentreArticlePage::get()->filter('ShowInMenus', '1')->filter('ShowInSearch', '1')->sort('Created', 'DESC');
    $pageArray = new ArrayList();

    foreach ($data as $page) {
        $page->AbsoluteLink = $page->AbsoluteLink();
        $pageArray->push($page);
    }

    // If I dump out the content of $pageArray here the object has the AbsoluteLink property  

    $jsonFormatter = new JSONDataFormatter();
    $jsonData      = $jsonFormatter->convertDataObjectSet($pageArray);

    // If I dump out the content of $jsonData here there is no AbsoluteLink property

    $this->response->addHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    return $jsonData; 
}
```

**The problem:**

The AbsoluteLink property is removed after running the `$pageArray` through the `convertDataObjectSet` method.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where you have the comment `// If I dump out the content of $pageArray here there is no AbsoluteLink property` did you mean if you dump out the comment of $jsonData, or is the data actually lost from $pageArray as you say?

Comment: Ah good pick up, that is indeed meant to be $jsonData, will update now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$jsonFormatter->setCustomAddFields();` will help here.

Add the following to the Page class:

```
public function getMyAbsoluteLink() {
    return $this->AbsoluteLink();
}
```

For example to the Page.php:

```
class Page extends SiteTree {
    public function getMyAbsoluteLink() {
        return $this->AbsoluteLink();
    }
}
```

And use that "magic field" like this:

```
public function json() {
    $pages = Page::get()
        ->filter('ShowInMenus', '1')
        ->filter('ShowInSearch', '1')
        ->sort('Created', 'DESC');

    $jsonFormatter = new JSONDataFormatter();
    // add your custom field
    $jsonFormatter->setCustomAddFields(["MyAbsoluteLink"]);
    $jsonData = $jsonFormatter->convertDataObjectSet(
        $pages
    );

    return $jsonData;
}
```

Note the `$jsonFormatter->setCustomAddFields(["MyAbsoluteLink"]);` and I removed the array manipulation.

Also I removed your array manipulation. How the `convertDataobjectSet` function works it seems you can't amend the objects before it runs.

Comment: That fields parameter will only return the fields specified. If I add AbsoluteLink to this the objects come back empty: $jsonFormatter->convertDataObjectSet($data, array('AbsoluteLink'));

Comment: Yes that function returns only the fields specified as stated in the documentation but as a case example it should work.  funcion AbsoluteLink () doesn't follow the convention so that it would work directly. You need a method that starts with public function getMyMagicMethod. E.g note the get in the beginning. If I remember correctly. Anyways back on my work computer so I might have time to fire up a real working example.